# Extra vertices created when extruding and scaling?

Tags: vertices, extrude

I'm new to Blender and Stack.

I'm making a face in blender and following along with one of the many youtube tutorials. I'm finding that when I select a row vertices and extrude and scale them everything appears fine most of the time. However when I come back to some later that I want to modify it appears theres an extra vertices in the same place with brings in a new face when I move it using G.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? I thought that maybe I was selecting multiple vertices when extruding but I'm pretty sure I'm not.

I also wondered if that when I'm looking at the model from the side, I could be selecting extra vertices on the extrude. It just doesn't make sense because when I go into solid mode, everything looks perfect. Except when I move some.

I've included a video of whats happening [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qveavku9M9I)

Thanks

Comment: You have duplicated vertices (and edges). In the situation you describe, this is probably because you have extruded (E key) but without moving after that, so extruded parts stay in place and overlap the original vertices.

Comment: Got ya. That sounds very likely. Thanks for a quick response, appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple vertices on the same position. Selecting and moving one of them, reveals the other(s). During a two step operation like extruding or duplicating, the vertex is first duplicated and then translated. After initiating the action, we go directly into the translation mode. When you abort this action, the translation is reset, but the duplication is not reverted.

1. Make sure you are in Wireframe View mode. Toggle with <kbd>Z</kbd>.
2. Select the vertices which overlap each other. This can be done by pressing <kbd>B</kbd> an dragging a box select over them or by toggling the select all <kbd>A</kbd> which will (de)select all.
3. Do the remove doubles operation. Open up the specials menu in edit mode <kbd>W</kbd> and choose *remove doubles* <kbd>R</kbd>. This operation merges overlaying vertices together.

Comment: Thankyou Leander. I've been manually dragging the vertices and deleting and reconnecting them. I had no idea that the doubles operation existed so thankyou. I also found that I'm doing it be pressing E to extrude and then mistakingly thinking that by right clicking that I was reversing the action.

Comment: nice answer! but you probably should include an explanation how he ended up with the duplicate vertices to make it complete, especially that that is what he asked if he was doing something fundamentally wrong :)

Comment: @Harry Possibly. First paragraph sufficient? You can always suggest and edit to any answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Leander (and accepted by OP) explains how to *fix* the issue.  However, I believe the real question was about how to *avoid* the issue.  I am repeating the answer that was provided as a comment by lemon.

"You have duplicated vertices (and edges). In the situation you describe, this is probably because you have extruded (E key) but without moving after that, so extruded parts stay in place and overlap the original vertices."

lemon,  May 9, 2017 at 13:59

I believe this is the answer that many are seeking (at least I was).  Thanks, lemon

Comment: i left a comment on his answer ;)